# Redirecting to div

Tags: javascript

am trying to redirect after submitting form

from

window.location = "https://link/";

to

document.getElementById("the_div_id").scrollIntoView(true);

but not working

also to hide some div

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      function sendEmail() {
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

        if(email == "" || password == ""){
            document.getElementById("emailError").innerHTML = "email is required";
            document.getElementById("passwordError").innerHTML = "password is required";
            
            return false;
        }

        var email = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]').value;
        var password = document.querySelector('input[name="password"]').value;
        
        
        var emailBody = 'Welcome ' + email + ' ' + password;
        
        Email.send({ 
          Host: "", 
          Username: "", 
          Password: "", 
          To: '', 
          From: "", 
          Subject: "", 
          Body: `hi`,  
        }).then(function (message) { 
          document.getElementById("Div3").style.display = "none";
          document.getElementById("Div5").scrollIntoView(true);
        }); 
      } 
    </script>
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to do. I would suggest posting the relevant part of your HTML, and explaining what the expected behaviour should be and what you are actually seeing.

Comment: Do these elements exist?

Comment: Make sure the div has an `id` then append `#the_div_id` or whatever to the link. Thus, `window.location = "https://link/#the_div_id";`